# Solr is showing data in search for some time only, after some time results get disappear

Tags: solr

Hi I am facing a problem with Solr earlier everything was fine but after restart of server Solr is showing only those documents that was indexed before restart. Whenever I create new document then it get indexed and commit also work and solr shows it in result but after some hour result get disappear from the search result. Before server restart it was not happening.I dont know why it is behaving like this now.

I observed index data when I index newly created data then its(index folder) size get increased and result shows document in result and after sometime size back to same size that was earlier and result also get disappear.

I am using tomcat 6.0 plugin tx_Solr 2.8.0 and Solr 4.2.0

Can anyone let me know why its now deleting newly created indexes only? Devlog Shows a delete query gets fire but I dont know why it is happening like this.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Sounds like you have the deletionpolicy active. Check and see if the deletionPolicy is uncommented in the solrconfig.xml

Comment: I have checked that no deletion policy is active. It is already commented in solrconfig.xml.

Comment: I saw cli_scheduler is deleting index. But i don't know how can i stop this deletion.Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Now I ahve resolved this by myself by commenting some code in plugin file.Now evrything is running fine. Thanks for other to giving their suggestions on it.

Comment: Can you please paste steps to comment code to stop this? I am also experiencing the same.